# python 3 best way function private object

Tags: python-3.x, function, private-members

I would like to reshape numpy array and send it to neural network for prediction, instead of calling `reshape` and create new object (which must be costly) I would like to have faster code - keep function "private" variable/object with proper shape and simply copy values into this object

is it a best pythonic way to create this variable `__reshaped_board` like bellow?
whole idea with starting underscores is to signal that this is private variable and do not use it :)

```
def predict_move(self, board, __reshaped_board=np.zeros([1, 4, 4, 1])):
    np.copyto(__reshaped_board[0, :, :, 0], board)
    return self.model.predict(__reshaped_board)
```

one possible solutions is to keep `copyto` outside of this function but calling this function in several places would require to make wrapper/decoator to this function

!! I keep in mind that this object will be created once when interpreter will evaluate definition of function and if somewhere I will reassign this reference then original object will be lost

Comment: what happens if function is called with 2 arguments? use an instance attribute instead

Answer (score 1):

Besides other drawbacks (bad readability, ability for callers to mistakingly passing 2 parameters to your method), your method is going to share this data all across instances of your object. Is that what you want?

what's wrong with instance attribute that will keep your storage all along object life?

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__reshaped_board = np.zeros([1, 4, 4, 1]

def predict_move(self, board):
    np.copyto(self.__reshaped_board[0, :, :, 0], board)
    return model.predict(self.__reshaped_board)
```

if you want to share across all instances just define your variable outside `__init__` to create a class variable.

```
 class Whatever:
     __reshaped_board = np.zeros([1, 4, 4, 1]
```

Comment: when I would like to have more transformations like this (this transformation is for performance only) then I will have to have more trashy references like this... I would like to keep it in one place

Comment: then create a dictionary or a sub-class.